# Measuring dimensions of svg elements in Angular

Tags: angular, svg

I am trying to create a gauge like component in Angular using SVG to draw the shapes. I would like to center the text within a rectangle. The text will change depending on the value of the gauge, therefore, I would like to either adjust the font size such that the value fits in the rectangle. Alternatively, I could adjust the number format (e.g. scientific notation if the string is too long) such that it fits the rectangle.

The problem I am having is that when I attempt the measure the dimensions of the svg elements (both the rectangle and the text), the `getBoundingClientRect()` for the native elements return zero. I am getting the native element via `@ViewChild() : ElementRef`. Is there a better way to do this?

I have put together a stackblitz that shows the issue when attempting to get the dimensions of the text. It differs to my local copy in that the rectangle does return a dimension. I am using Angular 5.2.11, perhaps the difference is due to differing versions?
Edit: 
I have updated the stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oz72py

I am adding the app.component.ts and its html template below

```
import { Component,OnInit, ViewChild,ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  @ViewChild('containerRect') containerRect : ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('valueText') valueText : ElementRef;
  valueStr="2512323.0";
  ngOnInit()
    {
    console.log('container bounds:',
                this.containerRect.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().width);
    console.log('text bounds:',
                this.valueText.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().width)
    }
}
```

The app.component.html:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 120 120">
  <svg:rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="00AA00"/>
  <svg:circle cx="60" cy="60" r="60" fill="#C3002F"/>
  <svg:path d="M 60 110
               A 50 50 0 1 1 110 60
               L 100 60
               A 40 40 1 1 0 60 100
               Z" 
               fill="#DDDDDD" fill-opacity="1"/>
  <svg:path d="M 60 110
               A 50 50 0 0 1 10 60
               L 20 60
               A 40 40 1 0 0 60 100 
               Z" 
               fill="#888888" fill-opacity="1"/>
  <svg:rect #containerRect x="29.090373558749814" 
                           y="51.717790556719336"
                           width="61.81925288250037"
                           height="16.564418886561327"
                           fill="#00AA00"/>
  <svg:text #valueText font-size="14px" 
                       x="50%" text-anchor="middle"  dy="0.95em"
                       y="51.717790556719336">{{valueStr}}</svg:text>
</svg>
```

Comment: The stackblitz link displays a little text, but doesn't seem to do anything else.  Do you have the correct URL?

Comment: @PaulLeBeau I think I had not saved the example in stackblitz :). I have saved it and the link should work ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DOM is not ready when `ngOnInit()` runs.

Instead, put your code in an `ngAfterViewInit()`

```
ngAfterViewInit()
{
  console.log('container boundsx:',
              this.containerRect.nativeElement.getBBox().width);
  console.log('text bounds:',
              this.valueText.nativeElement.getBBox().width)
}
```

I also recommend that you use `getBBox()` instead of `getBoundingClientRect()`. The `getBBox()` method returns values in SVG units. So it should be a bit more accurate, won't be affected by any scaling, and matches exactly the sizes in the SVG file.

Comment: Awesome! This sorts my problem and got to learn about getBBox() :)